# Calling javascript variables from a separate HTML/php file

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a separate javascript file(buy.js) from my html file(pay.php) that the html file posts to once a form is submitted. However, there are some javascript variables in pay.php that are outside the scope of the form that I need to call in the separate javascript file (buy.js). Is this possible to do?

This is the snippet of javascript that I need to access in my html file (buy.js):

```
  var planTerm = term;
```

This is the javascript in the html that I need the separate javascript file to access (pay.php):

```
var term = 0;
var price = 0;

function updatePrice(e) {
     price = parseFloat(select.value);
    if (price == select.options[1].value){
        term = 12;
    } else if (price == select.options[2].value) {
        term = 1;
    }
}
```

[Here is a Pastie of all the code.](http://pastie.org/8703022)

Comment: is it in a remote directory?

Answer (score 0):

Using PHP you can simply do (using the [include()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) function):

```
include("File.php");
```

So, as my example goes,

`The JS_INCLUDE.php File`:

```
<html>
<body>
  <script>
    var JSvar = "This is a external JS var.";
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

`The index.php`

```
<html>
<body>
    <?php
    include("JS_INCLUDE.php");
    ?>

    <script>
    document.write(JSvar);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

But of course if the .php file is remote from the directory, you cannot.

Sources:

Include() function: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php